# Why does my page stop loading too early on iphones? Express.js

Tags: javascript, ios, express, http, server

I'm downloading a file from a server using got, then editing the filestream and finally piping it to the response. When I open my page on my laptop, it keeps loading until the stream ends and when it ends it works fine and I can view the edited video. But when I open my page on my iPhone it loads for a bit then stops loading too early and the file doesn't get fully loaded. How do I fix this? Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
app.get('/stream-video', async(req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');

  try {
    let address = 'address here';

    let readStream = got.stream(await address);

    readStream.on('downloadProgress', ({
      transferred,
      total,
      percent
    }) => {
      res.setHeader('Content-Length', total);

      if (transferred === total) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          res.status(200);
          console.log('Finished downloading');
          readStream.destroy();
          return;
        }, 500);
      };

      let percentage = Math.round(percent * 100);
      console.log(`progress: ${transferred}/${total} - (${percentage}%)`);
    });

    readStream.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(`Download failed: ${error.message}`);
      res.send('Internal Server Error');
    });

    readStream.on('end', () => {
      console.log('end');
      setTimeout(res.end, 500);
    });

    res.status(206);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType[ext]);
    res.setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `inline; filename="player${ext}"`);

    // stream gets edited here

    readStream.pipe(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  };
});
```

And this is how I'm embedding the video:

```html
<video controls playsinline>
    <source src="/stream-video?id=<%= id %>" type="<%= _contentType %>">
</video>
```

It should work fine on iPhone since it works everywhere else but idk why its doing this, maybe I should make it keep loading until the stream ends but idk how to do that even after googling